# Fastest way to find different rows in two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two almost identical tables. Second one is a "slave" of first one. First table has autoincrement int ID column and second also has ID2 which is indexed unique int, but not autoincremented. ID2 is an analog of ID.

I need to find fastest way to detect new rows in second table (those ID2 which not exist in first table) and vise versa, new rows in first table (those ID which not exist in second table). A fastest way I found is

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE
    tab1.ID
from `tab1`
left join `tab2` 
    on tab1.ID = tab2.ID2
where
    isnull(tab2.ID2)
```

Takes out 2.5 seconds on ~200k records. What you may propose to get faster result?

Comment: not sure if you can go faster. but your query gives "new" rows in one table only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Tab2 WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM Tab1 where 
        Tab1.ID= Tab2.ID)
```

I think this query would give you a little faster result.

Comment: Exactly, it takes 0.7 seconds! 3 times faster, very good! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is null`:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE tab1.ID
from `tab1` left join
     `tab2` 
      on tab1.ID = tab2.ID2
where tab2.id2 is null;
```

This performance should be equivalent to:

```
select tab1.id
from tab1
where not exists (select 1 from tab2 where tab2.id2 = tab.id);
```

But it is worth trying both approaches.

Note that these versions do the inverse of what you ask -- find rows in `tab1` that are not in `tab2`.  It should be obvious how to switch the logic, depending on what you really want.